# Nuxt.js auth: Redirect after login doesn't occur for nested routes, only basic routes

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js, okta

I'm trying to use the `@nuxtjs/auth` module for OAuth2 authentication from Okta in a web app.

My app has a URL structure like: `/browse/{folder}` to view images from a particular folder, where `{folder}` can be any string of text. This is accomplished by creating a top-level view called `browse.vue`, a folder called `browse`, and a child component within that folder called `_folder.vue`. See more on nested routes in the Nuxt.js documentation in more detail [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/).

[image: Screen Shot 2020-08-25 at 9.53.58 PM.png]

I've added the auth guard to the `_folder.vue` file. When I navigate to `/browse`, I'm redirected to `/login` and everything works perfectly from here with OAuth2 and Okta. When I'm returned to the app after logging in, I'm taken back to the `/browse` page.

However, when I navigate to a folder, like `/browse/Test`, I'm not redirected back to that folder after logging in. Instead, I'm returned to the `/` view of the app. From here, if I type the path in the address bar again, I am able to successfully view it as a logged in user. This indicates that the login was successful, but something about the redirect wasn't.

I noticed by looking at the cookies in the Firefox developer tools that an `auth.redirect` cookie is not created when I navigate to `/browse/Test`, so I think the auth module is not aware of where to redirect the user after logging in. When I navigate to `/browse`, the `auth.redirect` cookie is created, and the redirect occurs successfully.

Is there something I can do to make the auth module work for redirecting to these dynamic routes, or is this a bug with the module? Everything else about the module has worked perfectly in my app.

My auth configuration in `nuxt.config.js`, using `@nuxtjs/auth` version 4.9.1:

```
  auth: {
    fullPathRedirect:true,
    redirect:{
      callback:"/login",
      logout:"/"
    },
    strategies: {
      social:{
        _scheme: 'oauth2',
        authorization_endpoint: "https://{my-subdomain}.okta.com/oauth2/v1/authorize",
        scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
        access_token_endpoint: "https://{my-subdomain}.okta.com/oauth2/v1/token",
        response_type: 'id_token',
        token_type: 'Bearer',
        client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret:process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        token_key: 'id_token'
      }
    }
  }
```